# Gitlab-runner verifies correctly, but time-outs when trying to accept jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab runner set up on an on-prem server running Ubuntu 18.04 with shell as executor. This worked fine until my organization migrated to a new GitLab enterprise and runners registered on the new GitLab URL cannot set up contact properly.

The following error message is received:

> WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed runner=XXXXXX status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.enterprise-url.com/api/v4/jobs/request: Post https://gitlab.enterprise-url.com/api/v4/jobs/request: dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxx: i/o timeout

However, contact can be established if I manually run some commands, such as `sudo gitlab-runner verify` and `sudo gitlab-runner run`. Then the connection is established and in the latter case, it can even accept jobs.

I have tried to run curl as the gitlab-runner user, and the HTTP 1 connection was fine (which I believe gitlab-runner use).

> gitlab-runner@server:~$ curl -X POST -I https://gitlab.enterprise-url.com/api/v4/jobs/request
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

I believe the fact that running the gitlab-runner commands as root user works, should give some good hints as to what the issue could be, but I am not knowledgeable enough to know what else to check. All similar issues I found online were related to dockers, so thankful for any help!

Comment: I never managed to find the underlying cause of this issue. However, I restored full functionality by creating a systemd service running the `sudo gitlab-runner run` command, ensuring that contact can always be established.